# Not able to expand and collapse child row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using [basic datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html) to print dynamic values that are received from the back end. I also have a hidden child row for each row with some additional values of that parent row. There is a button in each parent row and I want that on click of that link the child of that parent row should expand and be visible to the user. This should happen for every row.Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lakshmipriya001/r5xn1gj9/8/)

However, when I am clicking on that button, the child row is not opening. Can anyone please help me with the solution

```js
$('table').on('click', 'tr.parent .det', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr.cchild').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.cchild {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Experience</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach($per_job as $job): ?>
    <tr class="parent">
      <td>
        <?php echo $job->name; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $job->location; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $job->experience; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="show-btn rd-details det">
                DETAILS
              </button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="cchild">
      <td>
        <?php echo $job->age; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $job->class; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $job->address; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $job->number; ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why are you not using built-in functionality like [child rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) or [responsive extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/column-control/classes.html)?

Comment: Not related to your question, but I tried this myself a while back and noticed that doing this in such a manner will mess up the pagination capabilities of the datatable. Just something to keep in mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

As far I see you have not defined the class open anywhere, so just define the class in existing CSS.

```
.open{
  display:block !important;
}
```

The `display` property specifies if/how an element is displayed.

Every HTML element has a default `display` value depending on what type of element it is. The default `display` value for most elements is `block` or `inline`. When you declare an object to have `display` `none` as you have done using your CSS for `cchild` the code hides the object.

Now to show your object you can either remove your existing class or override the existing class by using another class or style. To do so you are using toggling the class `open` which should have `display` '`block`'. In simple language, you are showing and hiding the object. More info can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_display_visibility.asp).

Comment: I have edited my reply. I think will be helpful to you. If satisfies please upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: Added important to force the class. try it now.

Comment: Can you show me the log inside the click event. $('table').on('click', 'tr.parent .det', function() {
console.log("coming here")
  $(this).closest('tr.cchild').toggleClass('open');
});

Comment: @ Ullas Hunka in console it is printing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176153/discussion-between-ullas-hunka-and-lakshmi-priya).